# Is it possible to specify what args to expect in a callback passed to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Let's say a have this component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   // ...
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  name: React.PropTypes.string,
  onChange: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

How can I tell what are the possible args that onChange is called with?

```
<MyComponent name="bar" onChange={(iDontKnowWhatsHere) => {}} />
```

Comment: Not really. A function can accept an arbitrary number of arguments of arbitrary types. Given a function, you might be able to test for the number of arguments it expects, but not what types it expects. Put differently: Even if you could specify it, there would be no way to test for it. Add a comment to the `onChange` propType instead.

Comment: Added to that, a function parameter description does not withhold a function to read out more arguments, by looking at `arguments`.

Comment: You might be interested in trying TypeScript, which allows you to define the type(s) for function parameters and will complain at compile time (typescript -> javascript) if they're not what's expected.

Comment: You should test your arguments in your function body. Nothing to do with react.

Comment: And if you don't want to buy into Typescript completely, you can try [flow](https://flowtype.org) which is also used in React Native.

Comment: Thank guys! I see it's not possible with what i have now.
Basically my idea was to generate some documentation for my components automatically. So anyone using my component knows what to expect from the onChange callback.